Does に in 間(に) matters when talking about spatial frame?
Dictionary of Japanese Grammar has an explanation about this

The non-temporal 間 which means 'space between' or 'relationship' is
used in the structure A と B (と) の間 'between A and B' as in:
(6). 日本とアメリカ(と)の間には海しかない。 There is only ocean between Japan and
America.
(7). 山口と僕(と)の間は決して悪くない。 The relationship between Yamaguchi
and me is not bad at all.

間 and 間に differs when talking about time duration, but what about spatial (distance)? Either literally, like sentence 6, or metaphorically (eg. relationship) like sentence 7.
Do their meaning change if I change sentence 6 from 間に to just 間, and vice-versa with sentence 7?

This question is similar to: は、には、に。。。what is the difference between them?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In other words, this isn't so much about the nuance of 間, but rather about how the combination には works.


(6): This is a well-known [place name] + には + [thing] + がある/ない construction, e.g., 日本には火山がある. AとBの間 is a noun phrase that simply refers to the space between A and B, and thus you cannot drop に after 間.

(7): You cannot use に because this 間 is not used with ある/ない. Actually, this 間 does not even refer to a place. (By the way, while this sentence is understandable, it's more natural to say 山口と僕との仲は決して悪くない.)


